# Patch isn't working

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

i'm using magento 2 path system but it's not working, when i do a setup upgrade it doesn't reach my die, could you explain me why ?

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Company\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerCompanyAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup 
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory     $customerSetupFactory 
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        die('potato');
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'company',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Company',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => true,
                'position' => 30,
                'system' => false,
                'source_model' => \MyVendor\Company\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Company::class
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'company')
            ->addData(
                [
                    'used_in_forms' => [
                        'adminhtml_customer'
                    ]
                ]
            );
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why. For peoples who has the same issue, check first you don't have created an installData like the old way to intall/upgrade your data.

If you want to migrate without duplicate your data, you should create a patch file for each install / upgrade data file you have and you could use the `\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface` to define a specific version.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html

Answer (score 15):

If you have already ran `setup_upgrade` before, there is a table in the database called `patch_list` that will be filled because patches are only executed once. You could go in the database and delete the entry and then run `setup_upgrade` again.

Comment: This is the main point to be noted.

Answer (score 3):

Include the below function and the given version should be greater than the version specified in `module.xml`

```
public static function getVersion()
{
  return '2.3.6';
}
```

Comment: This is the bit of critical information that was missing.

Comment: @Tschallacka This information is available in the documentation. Please check the last part of this article - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html#will-old-scripts-work-in-newer-versions